# TypeScript Declaration Files Cannot Find Error

Tags: typescript, declaration-files

message.js

```
function showMessage(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

message.d.ts

```
declare function showMessage(message: string);
```

DeclarationFiles.ts

```
showMessage("this is a message."); //Error: cannot find name 'showMessage'
```

contains cannot find error.

How to solve the error?

Comment: Did you export the function from message.js and import it in DeclarationFiles.ts?

Comment: thanks. I added them, and works.